# C# App Install Error - microsoft.visualstudio.hostingprocess.utilites.sync version 9.0.0.0 missing from Global Assembly Cache (GAC)

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-installer, setup-deployment

Background: I have a winforms app written in C# that converts xlsx files to csv by calling a 2nd entirely seperate application ConvertExcelTo.Exe from the command line.  I'm using the Build Publishing tool to compile a setup / install file out of the solution for the winforms app.

Problem: The Windows installer completes without any errors on my computer with Windows 7 Ultimate, Visual Studio 2010 Premium, and Framework 3.5 but the user operating on Windows XP SP3 without VS gets the following installation error message:

```
   This application requires microsoft.visualstudio.hostingprocess.utilites.sync 
   version 9.0.0.0 be installed in the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) first.
```

Under Prerequisites I have selected:

- Windows Installer 3.1
- .Net Framework 3.5
- Download prerequisites from the component vendor's website

Under Application Files I have:

- Included Files: CCP_Utility.exe, CCP_Utility.exe.config, CCP_Utility.exe.manifest, ConvertExcelTo.exe, ExcelConversion.dll, Icon1.ico, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll, Microsoft.Vbe.Interop.dll, office.dll
- Excluded Files: CCP_Utility.vshost.exe, CCP_Utility.pdb
- Prerequisite Files: Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.Sync.dll, stdole.dll

I've tried:

- Adding the existing items ConvertExcelTo.exe and ExcelConversion.dll to the Project Solution and deleting the References to these files externally
- Excluding ConvertExcelTo.vshost.exe from the Application's Files under the Build Pubisher and deleting the file from the Solution
- Installing the Windows 4.5 SDK for XP SP3 & Vista here: http://download.microsoft.com/download/7/c/4/7c426dfc-46e2-4ded-bab4-3b33600ad7d1/msi45sdk.msi

Question:

- What does the user have to download to get the installer to complete without errors?
- What do I need to edit in the Publisher so that other users don't get this error?
- Should I set any of the prerequisite files to be included files?

Thanks for looking! :)

Comment: @Hans, Where do I register assemblies in GAC by right clicking "File System on Target Machine" and select "Global Assembly Cache Folder"? Will doing this work for this example?

Comment: Erm, I never commented on this question.

Comment: @Hans, you commented on a similar question that dealt with GAC here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889906/registering-dlls-in-the-gac-using-visual-studio-installer

Comment: Do not deploy the app.vshost.exe file, it is only there for debugging. Only deploy the app.exe file. From your Release build folder. – Hans

Comment: @Hans, installing the Win 4.5 SDK and excluding ConvertExcelTo.vshost.exe from the Application Files and deleting it from the solution didn't prevent the same error from coming up on the end users machine. do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Do *not* install anything to the GAC.  You've done enough damage to the customer's machine already.  You need help from a more experienced team member, SO cannot be your backstop.

Comment: I'm signing off btw, this is too much.

Comment: Installing an SDK from microsoft won't damage a user's computer. At the most, it might use a little extra hard drive space on the user's machine but that's about it. The SDK can be uninstalled easily anyways. I was going off suggestions from a previous question for an easy quick fix. Haha If you don't have anything helpful, just say you don't know.

Comment: I just rephrased my question and added more information to make this question more clear and useful to others. Do you recommend adding anything else to the question?

Comment: @Brian, For what it's worth, whilst installing an SDK on an end users computer *probably* won't damage it (can you *prove* it won't? No. But then I can't *prove* it will! :-), surely you can see that even considering installing a **Software Development Kit** onto an end user machine to make an end user app, that converts Excel files to CSV files, work is **really** wrong? :) You're using Win7 so get yourself WindowsXP mode installed as a test environment for verifying installs **before** you give them to your customer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this issue by adding a Setup and Deployment project to my existing project to create an installer where I could select "Global Assembly Cache Folder" by right clicking "File System on Target Machine"

1. In the existing project, Go to File Menu > click Add > New Project > now the “Add New Project” dialog will appear.
2. Select the “Other Project Types” and click “Setup and Deployment” projects,Choose “Setup Project”give name project name in name text box finally click OK.
   [image: Project Types]
3. New project appear in solution explorer,for eg., you have give the name “myEXE” file will be displays with given name.
4. Right click the myEXE > go View 
   [image: File System]
5. You can see the “File System on Target Machine” under 3 folders: 
   Application Folder, User’s Desktop, & User’s Program Menu. Right click the "File System on Target Machine" and select "Global Assembly Cache Folder"
   [image: File System on Target Machine]
6. Select Application Folder and right click Add>Project Output>select Primary output
7. Select User’s Desktop richt click on the second window>click create new shortcut>select output file from Application folder>change the file name from  primary output name to myEXE
   8.Finally Build the new project After successfully Build the project myEXE(Setup) will be appear in Application Debug or Release folder(depend upon the properties settings)

I hope this helps others as well :)

Comment: Nine times out of ten, if you're having problems deploying your application to customers, the solution is going to be to create a setup program for them to run. It eliminates the possibility of missing dependencies, and is a *far* better choice than trying to (or getting them to try to) muck around with their system and copy missing files to the proper locations yourself. You should never install assemblies to the GAC manually. +1 for coming up with the right solution.

Comment: Thanks for the +1 @Cody, I needed something uplifting after the demoralizing down-vote on my question haha. I just rephrased my question to make it more useful to others. Do you recommend adding anything else to the question?

Comment: I don't understand why you need to add anything else to the question. Did this not solve the problem?